# Jquery UI selectmenu keycodes 115/116 preventing?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-selectmenu

https://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/ have very unusual event reaction on keycode **115 (F4)**. When u expand the list and click on **F4** button, *some* and *some+1* option selected for a change. In example from link - *first* and *second* option, but in my app *20* and *21* node of list :O.

Is a bug? It is possible to **prevent** this?

In my app i found second strange reaction on keycode **116 (F5)**. When u expand the list and click on **F5** button, some option is selected before reload a page. In my app it'ss **10**. Is not cool for me because i get some project to work. This project has event which send ajax request to save data in session on change selected option, but after click F5 app send ajax request before reload a page which change some attribute in session on **10** because as i said when u click F5 selectmenu change selected node on **10**.

Example:
https://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/ Click on selectmenu with title "Select a speed" and click F4

Its is possible to prevent this events?

Comment: Please add a [mcve] to your question.

Comment: Example is here https://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/ Click on selectmenu with title "Select a speed" and click F4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might change the selectmenu prototype like this (see and run the code snippet below):

```js
$(function() {

  var ok = $.ui.selectmenu.prototype._buttonEvents.keydown;
  $.ui.selectmenu.prototype._buttonEvents.keydown = function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 115 || e.keyCode == 116) e.stopPropagation();
    ok.call(this, e);
  }

  var a = $("#speed").selectmenu();

});
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
}

select {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<label for="speed">Select a speed:</label>
<select name="speed" id="speed">
  <option value="Slower">Slower</option>
  <option value="Slow">Slow</option>
  <option value="Medium" selected>Medium</option>
  <option value="Fast">Fast</option>
  <option value="Faster">Faster</option>
</select>
```